# Read two variables in a single line with Python

Tags: python, input

I am familiar with the input() function, to read a single variable from user input. Is there a similar easy way to read two variables?

I'm looking for the equivalent of:

```
scanf("%d%d", &i, &j); // accepts "10 20\n"
```

One way I am able to achieve this is to use `raw_input()` and then `split` what was entered. Is there a more elegant way?

This is not for live use. Just for learning..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, the usual way is `raw_input().split()`

In your case you might use `map(int, raw_input().split())` if you want them to be integers rather than strings

Don't use `input()` for that. Consider what happens if the user enters

> `import os;os.system('do something bad')`

Comment: Note that starting with Python 3.0, `raw_input` was renamed to `input`. (And to get the original behavior of `input`, use `eval(input)`.)

Comment: ...that should be "apply `eval` to the output of `input`".

Comment: Yes, the obvious behaviour in 3 is much better, but I wish they had dropped some warnings into 2.6 about those changes. I guess I need to study the upgrade guide

Comment: no it should be `int(input()`, if you do `eval(input())` in python3 you get a very dangerous backdoor because the user will be able to execute any python statement (even os.system) with your user's rights.

Comment: @dialloliogn: read again. I made a *general* remark about how to get Python 2's `input` behavior in Python 3.

Comment: How can I read multiple variables using this?
Eg: I am trying to read 4 variable inputted on a single line

Answer (score 11):

You can also read from sys.stdin

```
import sys

a,b = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
```

Answer (score 6):

I am new at this stuff as well. Did a bit of research from the python.org website and a bit of hacking to get this to work. The **raw_input** function is back again, changed from **input**. This is what I came up with:

```
i,j = raw_input("Enter two values:  ").split()
i = int(i)
j = int(j)
```

Granted, the code is not as elegant as the one-liners using C's **scanf** or C++'s **cin**. The Python code looks closer to Java (which employs an entirely different mechanism from C, C++ or Python) such that each variable needs to be dealt with separately.

In Python, the **raw_input** function gets characters off the console and concatenates them into a single **str** as its output. When just one variable is found on the left-hand-side of the assignment operator, the **split** function breaks this **str** into a **list** of **str** values .

In our case, one where we expect two variables, we can get values into them using a comma-separated list for their identifiers. **str** values then get assigned into the variables listed. If we want to do arithmetic with these values, we need to convert them into the numeric **int** (or **float**) data type using Python's built-in **int** or **float** function.

I know this posting is a reply to a very old posting and probably the knowledge has been out there as "common knowledge" for some time. However, I would have appreciated a posting such as this one rather than my having to spend a few hours of searching and hacking until I came up with what I felt was the most elegant solution that can be presented in a CS1 classroom.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly read the complete line into a string like

```
    string = raw_input()
```

Then use a for loop like this

```
    prev = 0 
    lst = []
    index = 0 
    for letter in string :
        if item == ' ' or item == '\n' :
            lst.append(int(string[prev:index])
            prev = index + 1
```

This loop takes a full line as input to the string and processes the parts in it individually and then appends the numbers to the list - lst after converting them to integers .

Answer (score 1):

you can read 2 int values by using this in python 3.6.1

```
n,m = map(int,input().strip().split(" "))
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this method for any number of inputs. Consider the following for three inputs separated by whitespace:

```
import sys

S = sys.stdin.read()
S = S.split()
S = [int(i) for i in S]
l = S[0]
r = S[1]
k = S[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do this

```
input_user=map(int,raw_input().strip().split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for taking inputs in one line

```
a, b = map(int,input().split())
```

Keep in mind you can any number of variables in the LHS of this statement.

To take the inputs as string, use ***str*** instead of ***int***

And to take list as input

```
a = list(map(int,input.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

in python 3.9 , use a, b = map(int,input().split())
because you will get raw_input() not defined