# How to read two inputs separated by space in a single line?

Tags: python

I want to read two input values. First value should be an integer and the second value should be a float.

I saw [Read two variables in a single line with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588058/python-read-two-variables-in-a-single-line), but it applies only if both the values are of same type. Do I have any other way?

Example input, first is int and second is float. The inputs should be on a single line:

```
20 150.50
```

http://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST/

I'm very new to Python.

Comment: The answer to the linked question is most of the answer you need.  What have you tried?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy mistake is mine. I should have read doc's first :(

Comment: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [20]: a,b = raw_input().split()
12 12.2

In [21]: a = int(a)
Out[21]: 12

In [22]: b = float(b)
Out[22]: 12.2
```

You can't do this in a one-liner (or at least not without some super duper extra hackz0r skills -- or semicolons), but python is not made for one-liners.

Answer (score 4):

One liner :)

```
>>> [f(i) for f,i in zip((int, float), raw_input().split())]
1 1.2
[1, 1.2]
```

Comment: Please explain each component of the line

Answer (score 4):

Simpler one liner(but less secure):

```
map(eval, raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 3):

If the input is separated by spaces " "

`a,b,c = raw_input().split(" ")`

If the input is separated by comma ','

```
a,b,c = raw_input().split(",")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.7, I use this

```py
A,B = raw_input().split(" ")
A = int(A)
B = float(B)
print(A)
print(B)
```

Output:

```
34 6.9

34

6.9
```

Answer (score 2):

`map(str,input().split())`           that is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet works for me.

```
>>> a,b=list(map(int,input().split()))
1 2
>>> print(a)
1
>>> print(b)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to take as many inputs as u want then following:

```
    x=list(map(str,input().split())) 
    print(x)
```

If you want two inputs:

```
   x,y=x,y=list(map(str,input().split()))
   print(x,y)
```

Comment: The result of `x=input().split()` is a list of strings so you are performing `map` and `list` unnecessarily. Oddly, you also have `x,y=x,y=` in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

This is good solution imho `a, b = input().split()`.

If you want to separate input with custom character you can put it in parenthesis e.g. `a, b = input().split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

Read 3 inputs separated by space...

```
arr = input().split(" ")
A = float(arr[0])
B = float(arr[1])
C = float(arr[2])
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5

Below snippet works for me.

```
a, b = input().split(" ")
a_value = int(a)
b_value = int(b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically you just need to use map function and pass user define function for which datatype you need to convert.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyVAH.png)

You can even use it to convert it into other datatypes as well

Comment: overkill for a simple task, please do not write [ninja code](https://javascript.info/ninja-code)

Answer (score -1):

In python 3
we can use,

```
r1,r2 = map(int,input().split(" "))
```

Comment: This way both numbers will be `int` while question specifies that second is float.