# map(eval, raw_input().split()) less secure?

Tags: python, security, eval, map-function

[Referring to this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162815/how-to-read-two-inputs-separated-by-space-in-a-single-line) a comment by "phoris" states that `map(eval, raw_input().split())` is less secure. Can somebody explain how is is it less secure and in what context?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Hardly so. That's a question about **lisp** not python. There are plenty of question specifically about python's `eval`, why close this as a duplicate to a lisp one?

Comment: By the way: that is **not** a comment, but an answer by Phoris. As such you could provide a link directly to the answer.

Comment: Also related [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any context. It puts user input through `eval()`, which is a gaping wide security hole.

Comment: Thanks for the short and crisp answer.